# Reorder 2D NumPy array based on two lists of rearranged labels

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that takes a 1D list of numeric labels and returns a 2D array (multiple 1D arrays corresponding to each label).  The problem is that the returned data is ordered based on a sorted list of the labels.  I need to revert it back into the original order of the labels.

For example, I have the following:

```
import numpy as np

labels = [20,12,11]         # desired order
labels_sorted = [11,12,20]  # sorted label order

#              labels:    11     12     20                          20     12     11
data_sorted = np.array([[345.3, 361.8 ,347.6],       # reverted: [[347.6, 361.8, 345.3]
                        [383.6, 402.0, 386.2 ],      #            [386.2, 402.0, 383.6]
                        [422.0, 442.2, 424.9 ],      #            [424.9, 442.2, 422.0]
                        [460.4, 482.4, 463.5 ],      #            [463.5, 482.4, 460.4]
                        [498.7, 522.5, 502.1 ]])     #            [502.1, 522.5, 498.7]]
```

My desired output in this case is for the 1st and 3rd columns to be swapped.  I managed to find a solution that gets my desired result.  But it mostly uses list operations.  I'm concerned that it's going to be slow for larger arrays (e.g., 1000x1000).  Is it possible to do this more efficiently with NumPy functions?

```
data_sorted_T = np.transpose(data_sorted)  # transpose array so it can be zipped correctly
combined_sorted = zip(labels_sorted, data_sorted_T)  # pair the labels with each data set
combined_reverted = sorted(combined_sorted, key=lambda s: labels.index(s[0]))  # rearrange order
#data_T = np.fromiter( [label[1] for label in combined_reverted], float)  # doesn't work
data_T = np.array([label[1] for label in combined_reverted])  # unzip
data = np.transpose(data_T)

print(labels_sorted)
print(data_sorted)
print(labels)
print(data)
```

Comment: Have you looked at `np.argsort`? Even a argsort of a argsort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get a sorting index array:

```
In [64]: idx=np.argsort(labels); idx
Out[64]: array([2, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
```

apply it to the `labels`:

```
In [65]: np.array(labels_sorted)[idx]
Out[65]: array([20, 12, 11])
```

and to the columns of the data

```
In [66]: data_sorted[:, idx]
Out[66]: 
array([[347.6, 361.8, 345.3],
       [386.2, 402. , 383.6],
       [424.9, 442.2, 422. ],
       [463.5, 482.4, 460.4],
       [502.1, 522.5, 498.7]])
```

You don't need to use `argsort`; just anything that specifies the order of the labels and columns.

Comment: Thanks.  This solution appears to be similar in speed, or up to 10x faster than the Pandas solution (the 2nd fastest).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the concept of "labels" has much meaning in the case of NumPy so I guess the best idea is to simply use the right tool for the job which would be pandas in this case:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

labels = [20,12,11]         # desired order
labels_sorted = [11,12,20]  # sorted label order

#              labels:    11     12     20
data_sorted = np.array([[345.3, 361.8 ,347.6],          
                        [383.6, 402.0, 386.2 ],         
                        [422.0, 442.2, 424.9 ],         
                        [460.4, 482.4, 463.5 ],         
                        [498.7, 522.5, 502.1 ]]) 

res = pd.DataFrame(data_sorted, columns=[str(i) for i in labels_sorted])
          .reindex(columns=[str(i) for i in labels]).values


Out:
array([[347.6, 361.8, 345.3],
       [386.2, 402. , 383.6],
       [424.9, 442.2, 422. ],
       [463.5, 482.4, 460.4],
       [502.1, 522.5, 498.7]])
```

Also to get performance similar or better compared to Numpy you can use Polars:

```
import polars as pl

res = pl.DataFrame(data_sorted, schema=[str(i) for i in labels_sorted])
         .select(pl.col(str(i) for i in labels)).to_numpy()
```

Comment: Interestingly, for the array sizes that I tested this on, the polars solution was consistently 10-100x slower than the Pandas solution.

Comment: @swimfar2, yeah it is strange. I've just tried arrays up to 10000*10000 in size and I don't see Polars being 100x slower but 10x with the accepted solution coming up in first and Pandas being about 1.5-2x slower. Interesting, I managed to mess up polars so much, I'll see if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is pass the `index list` to slice the 2d array.

Below is the one-line solution without any other libs.

```py
import numpy as np

labels = [20,12,11]         # desired order
labels_sorted = [11,12,20]  # sorted label order

#              labels:    11     12     20                             20     12     11
data_sorted = np.array([[345.3, 361.8 ,347.6],          # reverted: [[347.6, 361.8, 345.3]
                        [383.6, 402.0, 386.2 ],         #            [386.2, 402.0, 383.6]
                        [422.0, 442.2, 424.9 ],         #            [424.9, 442.2, 422.0]
                        [460.4, 482.4, 463.5 ],         #            [463.5, 482.4, 460.4]
                        [498.7, 522.5, 502.1 ]])

# # idea (description of the below answer)
# index_list = []
# for label in labels:
#     index_list.append(labels_sorted.index(label))
# data_sorted[:, index_list]

# ----------------
#     Solution
# ----------------
data_sorted[:, [labels_sorted.index(label) for label in labels]]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I especially like how you broke the algorithm down to make it easier to understand what it's doing.